# Measure time between trigger events

Tags: digital-logic, pulse, timing

I want to measure the arrival time of three seperate digital pulses with respect to a global trigger.

The longest arrival time is expected to be <10ms and it would need to be able to determine the arrival time to <1us

The jitter of the timing is more important than latency, as I will be comparing the three arrival times. Therefore any systematic errors can be ignored.

This will a part of a control system running at about 100Hz on a microcontroller.

What is the simplest solution in this case?

Comment: I would use a 4-Channel Scope with the required time-resolution.

Comment: This is a great example of why we have oscilloscopes.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough on the context. This will be running at about 100Hz and form a control system circuit

Comment: A micro with several timer-counters.

Comment: Is it common for microcontrollers to habe several timer-counters? Can they achieve sub-microsecond resolution? Any microcontroller suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at ATMega328p**B** which has three 16-bit timer counters.

Comment: Is it common? I don't know but multiple  microcontrollers have multiple timers, and even a single timer can have multiple timestamp input capture channels. An MCU that I am currently working with has up to 22 timers, but not all have input capture features. The timers that do typically have up to 4 capture channels, one of them has 10.

Comment: Thank you. In this context what is a capture channel. Is there a good source to learn more?

Comment: @Flemingjp Different MCUs call the same feature with different names. Which MCUs you are familiar with? Have you read how their timers work?

Comment: @Justeme AVR and ESP32, but only in the Arduino context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a MCU with 16-bit timer that has 3 input capture channels.

At least 1 us resolution means timer must run at least at 1 MHz. To measure up to 10ms, that's 10000 us. So a timer with 16 bits could measure up to 65ms, or you can run it faster like at 5-6 MHz to measure up to 13.1 or 10.9 ms to get more resolution.